# My Pivot table is incorrectly formatting the dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like my Pivot table to group my date data based on columns of MMM-YY. I format my cells this way before hand, however when I put them in the PIVOT, the data becomes unformatted, and it groups based on each individual day in the month.

If I format the data in the Pivot table, it will give me duplicates ( which I don't want) like "Mar-19, Apr-19,Apr-19". My Date  data is originally in DD/MM/YYYY (UK format) and I use Excel 2016.

Does anyone have any suggestions or techniques I could use to fix to fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the date axis in the pivot table and select 'Group'. You can then select how to group the data:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much!